# Problem at filling self declaration COVID – 19 Italy

Tags: air-travel, paperwork, italy, spain, covid-19

Good morning. I have seen that, in order to travel from an Italian airport to a Spanish one it is necessary to fill out the following form:

https://www.jet2.com/-/media/jet2/flights/pdf/travel-requirement-forms/Italy

There is a part about the national ID card:

[image]

My question is, what do they mean with the "by" and "resident" section?. The spanish national ID card contains the following information:

[image]

Comment: That form seems to be for arrival into Italy? For arrival into Spain there’s a link from https://www.jet2.com/flights/safe-travel/travel-requirements to https://www.spth.gob.es

Comment: Without further instructions from the airline: 'BY' would be the issuing authority of the ID. 'Resident' should be the town you are registered in.

Answer (score 10):

As noted in a comment, this is apparently the form for travel *to* Italy and not from Italy to Spain. That's why it seems modelled after the Italian national ID card and the information it contains.

In case you still have to provide the information, “By” is the authority issuing the document, for example a municipality or embassy. Italian identity cards and the documents issued by many other countries mention it but it seems your Spanish ID card doesn't. You could just write “Spain“ in that field.

“Resident“ is the place where you live or your address. I would just use the “lugar de domicilio” mentioned on your card.

This is highly unlikely to have any serious consequences, simply put something reasonable on the form.

Comment: As Italian I can confirm, nobody really cares about that field specifically.

Answer (score 4):

"By" means who the passport or document was issued by, meaning the country (or state, region etc.) that issued it. "Residence" means where you are resident, i.e. where you live.

Comment: Not the country,  but the name of the authority that issued the card. This can be anything between a city district to a country depending on the jurasdiction. Sample: **BA TEMPELHOF-SCHÖNEBERG BÜA 2**

Comment: @MarkJohnson If it's a passport, then the issuer is a country. Same as any other form where you give your passport details.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings My Passport: **9. Authority BEZIRKSAMT TEMPELHOF-SCHÖNEBERG VON BERLIN ; 11 Residence BERLIN**, so you write what is written on the ID or passport where such a field exists. As you can see here, it is not always a country.

Comment: On most Dutch passports it reads "Burg van [City]", which means "Mayor of [City]".